# Resolving Session Conflict: Integrating Multiple Social Media Platforms with Next.js and NextAuth

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I have encountered an issue where, after logging in with Google, I need to obtain access tokens for Twitter and LinkedIn in order to make API requests for posting. However, when using NextAuth, it changes my session to either Twitter or LinkedIn, whereas I need to keep my session data from the Google sign-in. How can I resolve this problem?

To resolve this issue, I may need to modify the implementation of NextAuth to handle multiple authentication providers without affecting the existing session data. Alternatively, I could explore different authentication strategies or libraries that support multiple providers while maintaining the desired session behavior.